# How to sign and encrypt hash with c# given only a keystore

Tags: c#, rsa, cryptoapi, private-key

I'm using a keystore that was created using vc 6.0 and the cryptoAPI. The keystore contains all the exchange/signature keys. So i can use the public keys just fine to encrypt data using RSA but when it comes time to sign or decrypt the data I cant seem to find how to decrypt using the private key.

I've seen lots of sites using 
rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

but in my keystore when i look at the certs all of the private keys do not exist.

// this is how i setup the store

```
public cryptTest(string storeName)
{
    store = new X509Store(storeName);
    this.storename = storename;
}
```

// this is how i get the certificate from the store

```
public X509Certificate2 getCertificate(string ID, certType ct)
{
    if (store == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
    {
        if ((ct == certType.exchange && cert.Subject.Contains("Exchange")) ||
            (ct == certType.signature && cert.Subject.Contains("Signature")))
        {
            if (cert.Subject.Contains(ID)) // if the ID match
            {
                // todo check date etc ! is cert still valid if not delete etc. 
                store.Close();
                return cert;
            }
        }
    }
    store.Close();
    return null;
}
```

but then in the certs they never have a private key, so how could i possibly decrypt or sign using the certs in the keystore ?

Thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

I think the [EncryptTo/DecryptTo: Encryption in .NET with CryptoAPI Certificate Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867080.aspx) article on MSDN should have the answers you need.